# Previewing dedicated server MySql not working

Tags: mysql, cpanel, dedicated-server

I am moving a clients website from one dedicated server to another. (UK2.net to Fasthosts.co.uk) and would obviously like to check everything has transfered correctly before making the final switch to avoid any downtime.

I have successfully transfered everything across such as MySql database, webpages etc. I have set-up the CPanel for the user as well and so now would like to check everything is working. I have manually gone through a lot of the CPanel to check things like the page locations, database etc but will now look at the physical side.

I know that I can view the site live in-browser following with http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username (substituting IP and username where needed) but this is where I encounter my problem. The site shows up fine but when clicking to a specific page some of the MySql queries are not working correctly, basically data is not showing up where it should be and I am wondering if this is just because it is a preview rather than the full thing or is there more to this? I have not altered anything of the website just transferred it across to the new server.

I know that this seems a bit long-winded to explain my problem but felt that it needed some back story! Thank-you in advance

Comment: Can't help you without you showing any debugging. Are there error messages? Warnings? Can you insert and select from a populated table? Data is not showing up where it is supposed to... missing some CSS files? Give us something to work with :)

Comment: There are no error messages or warnings etc. The site that is being transferred is http://www.webuyanywatch.co/ and as you can see on there there are lots of images of watches appearing when you select a brand etc. This is what is not showing up on the preview so instead of showing a watch it shows the default no image icon. Everything else on the site appears to be working fine. Hope that helps a bit more?